# Rank structure in the Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing research on the structure in the Schur complements and find an interesting phenomenon:

Suppose that A is from 5--pt laplacian. If I use nested dissection ordering and multifrontal method to compute the LU factorization and then check the last schur complement block, it has low-rank for the off-diagonal blocks.

But, when I use the same method to factorize $A - \lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is some positive value near the eigenvalues of A, then the last schur complement does not have the low-rank property.

I do not know whether the indefinite will change the structure in the schur complement or not. Can anyone provide some reference for this topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Helmholtz equations. Replace $\lambda \ge 0$ with $\omega^2$ and you are describing a factorization of the Helmholtz equation. You may be interested in [this paper](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/lexing/publications/sweephmf.pdf), which covers this exact issue. There is also [a nice review paper](http://www.unige.ch/~gander/Preprints/HelmholtzReview.ps.gz) which explains why Helmholtz equations are hard.

Comment: In Ying's paper, he showed that for 2D problem, the schur complement should have the low rank property. He only claims that for 3D problem,the low-rank property is not significant. My problem is a 2D problem, but it dose not have low-rank.

Comment: @Willowbrook: I think that you should give it a more careful read. The low-rank property is only argued to hold for 1d *subproblems* of the 2D problem, and only in the case where an absorbing boundary condition is used. If you introduce one into your formulation, I think that your off-diagonal ranks will significantly decrease, though they should still grow significantly with the problem size.